# How to access Request attributes and parameters on Symfony?

Tags: php, arrays, symfony, object

How to reach the parameters Array into the Request object? For example in doneAction(), I want to get the parameter from the url such as this example:

www.example.com/en/done?payum_token=76BQZfpdjV1rOGye_y5WZr0vOpkyCKm2vstkOsZvjOE

```
public function doneAction(Request $request)
{
    dump($request);
    dump($request->query);
    dump($request->query->getparameters());
}
```

[image]

When I try with `$request->query->getparameters()` I have got an error:

[image]

I also tried `$request->query->parameters`

[image]

Comment: http://api.symfony.com/2.3/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/ParameterBag.html or http://api.symfony.com/master/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/ParameterBag.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do:

```
$request->query->get('payum_token');
```

If you look at your debug, we see that the `query` is a `ParameterBag` object. So you can access the Symfony API and see what are the public methods provided by this class. For example for the `get` method:

http://api.symfony.com/3.4/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/ParameterBag.html#method_get

Note that this method returns null if the parameter isn't found. If you want to have another value if the parameter is not found, then pass it as the 2nd argument:

```
$request->query->get('payum_token', 'default_value');
```